# Изменение содержимого на странице Bitrix (Битрикс)

Tags: php, битрикс

Есть страница https://cdtrf.ru/education/

На ней текст и изоброжекние подгружаются как функция PHP

" alt="" title=" фото">

Но на данной странице все пусто, хотя на вложенных ей страницах (видно в скриншоте отметил зеленым) контент подгружается правильно. Не могу понять как исправить эту страницу, чтобы контент появился. Подскажите, в Битриксе а уж темболее PHP не разбираюсь.

Вот кусок кода:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-видимому, нет элемента инфоблока, который соответствует данной странице. Как определяется, какой элемент должен выводиться?